# Android WebView - Taking snapshot with drawingCacheEnabled(true) with nested scrolls on page

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I want to capture snapshot of Web View for displayed area using `drawingCacheEnabled(true)` and loading bitmap from there. The issue I am facing is that when I have a page with nested scrolls and I take snapshot of page with internal part scrolled down, the snapshot appears like complete page was scrolled down.

If anyone has ever faced this issue and know the solution, please help me.